# Sherman-Morrison formula for Hermitian updates

Tags: matrices, complex-numbers, inverse, hermitian-matrices

I have a problem in which, in principle I can apply twice Sherman-Morrison formula but it seems to me that for this case, there should be a simpler solution so my question is **"May the process described below simplified thanks to the fact that the matrix is Hermitian?"**. Moreover, invertibility of the matrices is known (for the particular matrices I use) never to be a problem (it is a consequence of some existence and uniqueness theorem).
Suppose I have an infinite hermitian matrix $A=(a_{i,j})_{i,j=0}^{\infty}$ and I want to find the inverses of the right-up corner diagonal matrices $A_n= (a_{i,j})_{i,j=0}^n$ for each value of $n$.
I could decompose $A_{n+1}$ as an $n \times n$ block containing $A_n$, $u:= ((a_{i,n+1})_{i=0}^n,0)$, $u^*$, the conjugate transpose of $u$, and the corner element $a_{n+1,n+1}$.
Call $B$ to the matrix containing the blocks $A_{n}$ and $a_{n+1,n+1}$ but zeros on the other positions. Then $B^{-1}$ is a matrix with blocks $A_n^{-1}$, a vector of zeros, and its transposed and $a_{n+1,n+1}^{-1}$.
Define $C$ the matrix equal to $B$ except that we update the last column by summing $u$ (so $C$ is also equal to $A_{n+1}$ substituting $u^*$ by zeros). From that, Sherman-Morrison formula, gives me the inverse of the matrix $C$, $C^{-1}$, depending on $B^{-1}$ and $u$ (the summing of a vector process can be considered as summing the matrix which is result of multiplying pointwise a vector $(0,...,0,1)$ with $((a_{i,n+1})_{i=1}^n,0)$).
Once I have the inverse of $C$, I can repeat the process to update with the transpose conjugate vector $u^*$ and form a matrix $D$ and apply Sherman-Morrison formula to obtain $D^{-1}$ from $C^{-1}$, and the elements of $u^*$.

It seems like the fact that everything is hermitian would be useful to reduce the number of steps here, right?

If I can work in abstract with this inversion process, this would have important applications in complex analysis.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure the fact that the matrix is Hermitian simplifies things much.  Rather than the Sherman-Morrison formula, use the more general Woodbury matrix identity, essentially reducing the problem to the solution of a 2x2 matrix.

A simplified version of it should work for you:

$$\left(B+CR\right)^{-1}=B^{-1}-B^{-1}C\left(I+RB^{-1}C\right)^{-1}RB^{-1}$$

Where:

$$B=\pmatrix{A_n&0\\0&a_{n+1,n+1}}$$
$$C=\pmatrix{u&e_{n+1}}$$
$$R=\pmatrix{e_{n+1}^*\\u^*}$$

And $e_{n+1}$ is the component unit vector (all $0s$ except the last coefficient which is $1$):

$$e_{n+1}=\pmatrix{0\\\vdots\\0\\1}$$

Let us define $v$ as $u$ with the last coefficient ($0$) dropped, so:

$$u=\pmatrix{v\\0}$$
$$C=\pmatrix{v&0\\0&1}$$
$$R=\pmatrix{0&1\\v^*&0}$$
$$I+RB^{-1}C=I+\pmatrix{0&1\\v^*&0}\pmatrix{A_n^{-1}&0\\0&a_{n+1,n+1}^{-1}}\pmatrix{v&0\\0&1}=\pmatrix{1&a_{n+1,n+1}^{-1}\\v^*A_n^{-1}v&1}$$
$$\left(I+RB^{-1}C\right)^{-1}=\frac{1}{1-a_{n+1,n+1}^{-1}v^*A_n^{-1}v}\pmatrix{1&-a_{n+1,n+1}^{-1}\\-v^*A_n^{-1}v&1}$$
$$C\left(I+RB^{-1}C\right)^{-1}R=\frac{1}{1-a_{n+1,n+1}^{-1}v^*A_n^{-1}v}\pmatrix{-a_{n+1,n+1}^{-1}vv^*&v\\v^*&-v^*A_n^{-1}v}$$
$$B^{-1}C\left(I+RB^{-1}C\right)^{-1}RB^{-1}=\frac{\pmatrix{-a_{n+1,n+1}^{-1}A_n^{-1}vv^*A_n^{-1}&a_{n+1,n+1}^{-1}A_n^{-1}v\\a_{n+1,n+1}^{-1}v^*A_n^{-1}&-a_{n+1,n+1}^{-2}v^*A_n^{-1}v}}{1-a_{n+1,n+1}^{-1}v^*A_n^{-1}v}$$

Or slightly cleaner:

$$B^{-1}C\left(I+RB^{-1}C\right)^{-1}RB^{-1}=\frac{\pmatrix{-A_n^{-1}vv^*A_n^{-1}&A_n^{-1}v\\v^*A_n^{-1}&-a_{n+1,n+1}^{-1}v^*A_n^{-1}v}}{a_{n+1,n+1}-v^*A_n^{-1}v}$$

And there you have your correction matrix which you subtract from $B^{-1}$ to get $A_{n+1}^{-1}$.

$$A_{n+1}^{-1}=\pmatrix{A_n^{-1}&0\\0&a_{n+1,n+1}^{-1}}-\frac{\pmatrix{-A_n^{-1}vv^*A_n^{-1}&A_n^{-1}v\\v^*A_n^{-1}&-a_{n+1,n+1}^{-1}v^*A_n^{-1}v}}{a_{n+1,n+1}-v^*A_n^{-1}v}$$
$$A_{n+1}^{-1}=\pmatrix{A_n^{-1}+\frac{A_n^{-1}vv^*A_n^{-1}}{a_{n+1,n+1}-v^*A_n^{-1}v}&\frac{-A_n^{-1}v}{a_{n+1,n+1}-v^*A_n^{-1}v}\\\frac{-v^*A_n^{-1}}{a_{n+1,n+1}-v^*A_n^{-1}v}&\frac{1}{a_{n+1,n+1}-v^*A_n^{-1}v}}$$

Computationally, the fact that $A$ is Hermitian simplifies things since $v^*A_n^{-1}$ is the Hermitian of $A_n^{-1}v$, but it may not simplify your theoretical work.

Comment: A better derivation would have been to use the blockwise matrix inverse formula.  The derivation above counts on $a_{n+1,n+1}$ being non-zero where the derivation of the blockwise matrix inverse formula does not.  In any case the formula above only requires that A be non-singular and $a_{n+1,n+1}-v^*A_n^{-1}v$ be non-zero.